# What is inside the Prawn Cocktail crisps flavour?

Tags: seasoning, restaurant-mimicry, chips

I'm looking to make something close-enough at home for a friend. I'm suspecting it doesn't actually have Prawns in it.

Comment: Just speculating (hence not in the answer box), but I would imagine you can use dried shrimp like you would find in an asian market.  If it has cocktail sauce flavor as well, that could be simulated with ketchup and horseradish.  That is what I would do in US though; since you call them crisps, I assume you are from a commonwealth nation.  May be different, but the dried shrimp thing is a start. pulse it in a spice grinder with some salt and garlic powder and sprinkle it on after frying.

Comment: I answered the question asked: "what's in the crisps". I don't have an answer as to "how can I make this at home",  sorry.

Comment: I like @JSM's idea of using dried shrimp, but use sparingly - those little buggers are *potent*.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're talking about Walker's brand, we can see the following ingredients list from [Tesco.co.uk](http://www.tesco.com/groceries/product/details/?id=256644773) (should match what's on your bag):

> Prawn Cocktail Seasoning contains: Flavouring, Sugar, Glucose, Salt, Citric Acid, Potassium Chloride, Dried Yeast, Dried Onion, Vale of Evesham Tomato Extract, Colour (Paprika Extract), Sweetener (Sucralose)

Nutritional yeast (which is what I assume the 'dried yeast' is) is often used in vegan recipes to simulate a cheesy flavor, so it's probably not that. You can imagine what sugar, glucose, salt, citric acid, tomato extract, and dried onion taste like. Potassium Chloride is commonly used as a salt replacement to lower the salt content of food without losing that salty flavor.

I suspect it's that first ingredient, 'flavoring'. You're probably talking about a product like this: http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/prawn-Flavor-O5557-used-in-puffed_1699947706.html?s=p

> prawn Flavor O5557 used in puffed foods
>
> 1. Professional and mature R&D team, Application team.
> 2. Manufacturer of flavor
>
> Origin: Jining city, Shandong Province, China.

Comment: Sounds... appetizing?

Comment: Hi! I just want to let you know that the alibaba product link is down. I didn't know if you'd want to find another or edit it out, so I left it alone!

Answer (score 5):

The operative word in prawn cocktail crisps is *cocktail*. They're  essentially Marie Rose sauce flavour, there's barely any prawn notes. Marie Rose sauce is usually tomato ketchup, mayo, a little Worcestershire Sauce, and cayenne. Should be easy to replicate at home.

Comment: How would you coat a fried potato with that? Aren't crisps = chips in British/American? Putting a wet sauce on a thin, fried potato does not sound tasty. If you could find dry or powdered versions of those things, I could see that working. [Ketchup](http://www.alibaba.com/showroom/ketchup-powder.html), [worcester](http://www.americanspice.com/worcestershire-powder/), some cayenne and a tiny pinch of dried shrimp. Work out the ratios until it tastes similar.

Comment: Naturally I mean the _flavours_ can be replicated somehow, as you say, with dehydrated versions.

Answer (score -1):

Prawn cocktail is in fact made of orange zest, salmon and chicken stock.

Comment: Seems like an answer to me, just had an odd "signature" (which isn't necessary here since your username appears by your answer). Not sure if this is *correct*, but still an answer.